# Android multiplayer development suggestion

Tags: android, multiplayer

what is the best game engine when developing an android application.

Its a multiplayer turn-based card game.

2-3 players needed.

I want it to be played at WLAN (local).

I want a game engine that is easy to use and has enough support.

P.S. I tried to build it using AndEngine but stopped. I can't fully understand the engines network logic and can't use it. so I'm considering switching to a different game engine that is easy to use and has a good documentation.

The game I'm developing is exactly like [this](http://apps.facebook.com/tongits/). Only that I'm building it on android.

Comment: You might need to tell us more about the game. What will it look like? How will the UI work? All these things are probably more relevant to your engine choice than the network interactions between players.

Just provide a bit more info about the game if you want us to point you in the right direction.

Comment: well to put it simply Im trying to rebuild this app into an android game [link](http://apps.facebook.com/tongits/)